# How to play two sounds continuously in one button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, avaudioplayer, avkit

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dql39.png)

I need to create one button which can run two sounds continuously.
My present code, the button can run SoundA and SoundB at the same time.
But I want user to click on one button which can play SoundA.
Then SoundA has finished, and then play SoundB automatically(right after SoundA has ended).
Thank you for your helping.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var audioPlayer1: AVAudioPlayer!
    @State var audioPlayer2: AVAudioPlayer!
    var body: some View {
     
          
            Button(action: {
                
                let sound1 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "soundA", ofType: "mp3")
                let sound2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "soundB", ofType: "mp3")
                
                self.audioPlayer1 = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound1!))
                self.audioPlayer2 = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound2!))
                
                self.audioPlayer1.play()
                self.audioPlayer2.play()
            }){ Text("Play sound")
                .frame(width:300, height: 100)
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
    
}
```

I also have tried, but it doesn't work.

```
self.audioPlayer1.play()
self.audioPlayer1.stop()
self.audioPlayer2.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the length of your first sound.

```
let duration = self.audioPlayer1.duration
```

Play your first sound..

```
self.audioPlayer1.play()
```

Insert length that you get into asyncAfter DispatchQueue and play second sound.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + duration) {
self.audioPlayer2.play()
            }
```

You can also hardcode seconds of your first sound or increase pause by adding more seconds. Hope that help..

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Thank you very much for your solution!